# Why are Samba shares visible to other users but only accessible through the admin user?

Tags: samba, sharing

I have a Linux server V20 and have set up Samba for file sharing. The shared folders are on the second hard drive, which has been set up to automount. The challenge is the shared folders can only be accessed by the admin account and only through Windows PCs.

The other Samba users can only see the shared folders through their Windows PCs, but cannot access them. They get this error:

```
You do not have permission to access this folder, contact the administrator
```

But I have added them to the `smb.conf` file under Valid users.

Comment: Is "linux server V20" Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: On the server, in a command line terminal, check the permissions on the "shared folders" with `ls -ld`. For a "shared folder" (Linux calls them "directories") to be searchable, it must have the eXecute bit set in it's permissions (`d--x--x--x` for Owner, Group, World). To open a file requires Read permission (`dr--r--r--`) on the directory (to get the file info) Read `man -a chmod`, and consider `sudo chmod 0755` the shared directories.

Comment: Are you asking about Ubuntu Core 20 server? (a different product to the more common 20.04; as Ubuntu has used *year* format for *snap* only products)

Comment: Do the non-admin Windows accounts get asked for a username and password when trying to connect?

Comment: after running ls -ld on the mount i get
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 20 12:04

Comment: Yes the non-admin users get asked for username and password that's when we get the you do not have permission message

Comment: ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
By set the permission for the mount point to 755:

chmod 755 /mountpoint